# How can I get an implementation-agnostic version of std::uniform_int_distribution?

Tags: c++, random, uniform-distribution

`std::uniform_int_distribution` accepts any of `<random`>'s PRNG's, including the ones that are consistent across implementations and platforms.

However, `std::uniform_int_distribution` itself does not seem to be consistent across implementations, and so I can't rely on being able to replicate them, even using a common PRNG and seed. This also affects dependent functionality, e.g. `std::shuffle()`.

So for example:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void printvector(const std::string& title, const std::vector<T>& v)
{
        std::cout << title << ": { ";
        for (const auto& val : v) { std::cout<<val<<" "; }
        std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
        const static size_t SEED = 770;
        std::minstd_rand r1(SEED), r2(SEED), r3(SEED);

        std::vector<int> vPRNG;
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) { vPRNG.push_back((int)r1()); }

        std::vector<size_t> vUniform;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> D(0,301);
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) { vUniform.push_back(D(r2)); }

        std::vector<size_t> vShuffled {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        std::shuffle(vShuffled.begin(), vShuffled.end(), r3);

        printvector("PRNG", vPRNG);
        printvector("UniformDist", vUniform);
        printvector("Shuffled", vShuffled);
}
```

Gives me different results on different systems, even though the PRNG itself is generating exactly the same numbers:

**System 1:**

```
PRNG: { 37168670 1020024325 89133659 1161108648 699844555 131263448 1141139758 1001712868 940055376 1083593786 }
UniformDist: { 5 143 12 163 98 18 160 140 132 152 }
Shuffled: { 7 6 5 2 10 3 4 1 8 9 }
```

**System 2:**

```
PRNG: { 37168670 1020024325 89133659 1161108648 699844555 131263448 1141139758 1001712868 940055376 1083593786 }
UniformDist: { 19 298 170 22 53 7 43 67 96 255 }
Shuffled: { 3 7 4 1 5 2 6 9 10 8 }
```

---

**How can I correctly implement a uniform distribution which *is* consistent across different platforms and standard-library implementations?**

Comment: Either build your own or include a third party library like boost.

Comment: @NathanOliver : I don't know that boost gives me any better guarantee than c++11 does. I did check using Crypto++, and that _also_ gave differing results. Which makes me think a self-implementation might be more complex than it sounds... I'd be very glad for pointers to a third party library that _does_ give a guarantee, or pointers for a (non-platform dependant) self-implementation.

Comment: Boost's distribution should be portable because it uses the same implementation.  The stand version is not because even though they define the probability there are multiple implementations to get there and the different vendors can/do use them.

Comment: a simple way is to pick *some vendor's* std::uniform_int_distribution implementation, and copy it in another namespace. (with appropriate regard to licence)

Comment: Boost generally comes with weak compatibility guarantees. E.g.  (binary) 
 Boost.Serialization 1.58.0 might be incompatible with 1.59.0 or across platforms. The implementation of Boost's `uniform_int_distribution` may not be likely to change but still I wouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a truly uniform distribution, using rejection sampling to overcome the modulo problem. Rejection sampling is not a problem if the range (`b - a + 1`) is "short", but for very large ranges it can be problematic.
Make sure that `b - a + 1` does not under/overflow.

```
template <class IntType = int>
struct my_uniform_int_distribution
{
    using result_type = IntType;

    const result_type A, B;

    struct param_type
    {
        const result_type A, B;

        param_type(result_type aa, result_type bb)
         : A(aa), B(bb)
        {}
    };

    explicit my_uniform_int_distribution(const result_type a = 0, const result_type b = std::numeric_limits<result_type>::max())
     : A(a), B(b)
    {}

    explicit my_uniform_int_distribution(const param_type& params)
     : A(params.A), B(params.B)
    {}

    template <class Generator>
    result_type operator()(Generator& g) const
    {
        return rnd(g, A, B);
    }

    template <class Generator>
    result_type operator()(Generator& g, const param_type& params) const
    {
        return rnd(g, params.A, params.B);
    }

    result_type a() const
    {
        return A;
    }

    result_type b() const
    {
        return B;
    }

    result_type min() const
    {
        return A;
    }

    result_type max() const
    {
        return B;
    }

private:
    template <class Generator>
    result_type rnd(Generator& g, const result_type a, const result_type b) const
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<typename Generator::result_type, result_type>::value, "Ups...");
        static_assert(Generator::min() == 0, "If non-zero we have handle the offset");
        const result_type range = b - a + 1;
        assert(Generator::max() >= range); // Just for safety
        const result_type reject_lim = g.max() % range;
        result_type n;
        do
        {
            n = g();
        }
        while (n <= reject_lim);
        return (n % range) + a;
    }
};

template<class RandomIt, class UniformRandomBitGenerator>
void my_shuffle(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, UniformRandomBitGenerator&& g)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type diff_t;
    typedef my_uniform_int_distribution<diff_t> distr_t;
    typedef typename distr_t::param_type param_t;

    distr_t D;
    diff_t n = last - first;
    for (diff_t i = n-1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        std::swap(first[i], first[D(g, param_t(0, i))]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The boilerplate from Jonas answer was actually very useful. I'm sorry for the harsh criticism. Anyway, it is very important to avoid bias in a uniform distribution. The easiest way to achieve this is to "reroll" when the value provided by the random generator is outside the largest range that allows for unbiased mapping. This assumes the generator's result type has at least the same bitlength as the distribution's result type (otherwise it may be necessary to use multiple generator result values at once). Another important consideration is avoiding integer overflow when `b - a + 1` would overflow `result_type`. So there are three main caveats:

- Beware if `URNG`'s `result_type` has less bits than distribution's
- Beware of bias
- Beware of integer overflow

Given these challenges, it is unsurprising that Boost's implementation has more than 150 LOC (including comments). I'd recommend sticking with one of the available implementations if at all possible because it is so easy to screw this up. The problem with Boost is the algorithm may change with or without notice between versions. You could solve this by copying the Boost code so you don't have to rely on a given version. This may mean your program may have cross platform "bug for bug" compatibility – if you're unlucky. (This problem may occur with any implementation short of provably correct ones, of course.)

Also check the license terms, obviously, before copying any library code into your project. E.g. I think if you copy libstdc++'s implementation this may mean you have to distribute your program under GPL and copyleft.

Comment: You present some good points. In my new answer I don't handle the overflow possibility of `b - a + 1`, but the rest are handled.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is very important to avoid bias? I have, personally, never really needed a perfect uniform distribution.

Comment: @Jonas : For any particular given use, it really might not be an issue! But as a ground-level utility that other code takes for granted, non-uniformity can be a an error that's both very well-hidden and can have serious consequences. Better to get it perfect _once_, than need to check every time "OK, is this unbiased enough for _this_ time?".

Comment: @Ziv That is a fair point. But, given the suggested implementation it also raises a new issue: "OK, is this 'reroll' technique something I can tolerate _this_ time?"

Comment: @Jonas That may be my personal *bias* that library code should do what it promises, as Ziv mentioned. Getting more input values has the obvious disadvantage of unbounded worst case performance, which may be unacceptable in a real time (in particular a mission critical) system, but then again, the OP asked for uniformity and not speed.